# Paging results from a complex SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, paging

What's the best way to page the results from a complex query in SQL Server 2005 and 2008?

I came up with the following approach:

1. Perform the query, save its results to a table variable or temp table.
2. Use the following code:

   ```
   DECLARE @Rows INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @TableVariable)

   DELETE TV
   FROM   @TableVariable TV
   JOIN   (SELECT TV2.PrimaryKey, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...) AS RowNo
           FROM   @TableVariable TV2) N ON TV.PrimaryKey = TV2.PrimaryKey
   WHERE N.RowNo < @FromRow OR N.RowNo > @ToRow

   SELECT PrimaryKey, SomeComputedField, ...
   FROM   @TableVariable

   RETURN @Rows
   ```

However, I don't have any experience paging huge datasets myself. What do other SOers have to suggest?

Comment: sorry.. premature enter key...

Comment: Maybe this [link](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/server-side-paging-using-sql-server-2005) might be also useful for SQL Server 2005 users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A STORED PROCEDURE body could be written as:

```
;WITH rownums AS (
    SELECT  tempTable.[link], 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY tempTable.[link]) AS rownum 
    FROM    <temptable here> AS tempTable
)
SELECT  tempTable.link
FROM    <temptable here> AS tempTable
        INNER JOIN rownums AS rn
        ON  rn.[link]   =   drn.[link]
WHERE   rn.[rownum] BETWEEN @low AND @high
```

Then you would need to provide the STORED PROCEDURE with the range (@low and @high) and you would need the temp table of course.

P.S.  Also, I think your variable declaration will only work on 2008, if I remember correctly 2005 does not support single line instantiation and initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the correction regarding inline initialization of variables in SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1):

If your dataset is large, a @table will not perform well.  Your row_number can also be optimized a little not to go past @ToRow

```
JOIN   (SELECT TOP(@ToRow) TV2.PrimaryKey, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...) AS RowNo
        FROM   @TableVariable TV2
        ORDER BY ... -- same clause as ROW_NUMBER()
```

I would have gone down the route of Stored Proc, populating a #table (using the TOP as shown above), at the same time either SELECT INTO using IDENTITY(int,1,1) or pre-creating the table with an identity (clustered), then instead of DELETE then SELECT (2 ops), just SELECT from the #temptable based on

```
WHERE id-column between x and y
```